# ' t3lib_div::makeInstance ' not working in TYPO3 V6.2.x

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

am using TYPO3 v6.2.x 
I tried one extension using created in v4.1.x

But `t3lib_div::makeInstance` code not working in TYPO3 v6.2.x

How can i rewrite following code

```
$this->myRepository = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_newExt_Domain_Repository_myRepository');
```

in TYPO3 v6.2.x

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

Added full files for reference

My controller placed in location

" typo3conf/ext/new_extension/Classes/Controller/TTBAnbieterController.php "

```
    class Tx_NewExtension_Controller_TTBAnbieterController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {

    /**
     * @var Tx_NewExtension_Domain_Repository_TTBAnbieterRepository
     */
    protected $tTBAnbieterRepository;


    public function initializeAction() {          

        $this->tTBAnbieterRepository = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Tx_NewExtension_Domain_Repository_TTBAnbieterRepository');
        $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = Tx_Extbase_Dispatcher::getExtbaseFrameworkConfiguration(); 
        $HeaderData = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='xxxxx'/>";
        $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData($HeaderData);  
        $this->tTBLocationsProdukteGruppenRepository->CreateSpecialSeoTitle();

    }
}
```

My Repository placed in location

"/typo3conf/ext/new_extension/Classes/Domain/Repository/TTBAnbieterRepository.php"

```
class Tx_NewExtension_Domain_Repository_TTBAnbieterRepository extends Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Repository {


         public function getSelectedAnbieter($iAnbieterOfLocation)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tx_NewExtension_domain_model_ttbanbieter WHERE uid = '".$iAnbieterOfLocation."' ";
            $data = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql(TYPO3_db, $sql);  

            $aResults = array();
            $iCount = 0;
            while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($data)) {

                $aResults[$iCount] = $row;
                $iCount++;           
            }

            return $aResults;        
        }

    }
```

This is the full code for Controller and Repository.

Comment: Show us your repository class - whole, exactly as it is

Comment: @biesior     I added the full code..please chek

Comment: In first moment I thought that's matter of case, as you corrected, clear the  __system__ cache, also consider using injection as Daniel suggests. and remember do not use the `t3lib_*` classes anymore, they are depreciated in 6.x and __removed__ in 7.x +

Comment: @biesior  ys it worked. Now am facing with another problem. " Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\Widget\\PaginateViewHelper::render() must implement interface TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\QueryResultInterface, array given in /var/www/dev/ti-typo3/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Widget/PaginateViewHelper.php on line 67" . Can u Help me for this.

Comment: You need to use Extbase queries and return it instead of array... Anyway be careful with Paginate VH it can be real __performance killer__! (it repeates some DB operations so will slow down your page, especially with large sets of data),  it's better to write custom paginator

Comment: @biesior How can I remove this error. Am struck with it.

Comment: as I wrote: `You need to use Extbase queries and return it instead of array...` see this nice blog post to see how to create extbase queries: http://blog.typoplanet.de/2010/01/27/the-repository-and-query-object-of-extbase/  i.e. `public function findRecentByBlog(...`

Comment: @biesior : thank you.... lemme check it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dependency injection to let extbase handle the initialization of your dependencies for you.

```
/**
 * @var \Tx_newExt_Domain_Repository_myRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $myRepository;
```

Comment: Where should i give this??

Comment: in your controller. Add @inject to your property and remove the line with the makeInstance. Clear the cache and it will work.

Comment: Now am facing with another problem. " Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\Widget\\PaginateViewHelper::render() must implement interface TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\QueryResultInterface, array given in /var/www/dev/ti-typo3/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Widget/PaginateView‌​Helper.php on line 67" . Can u Help me for this.